# Bad host link in Arduino program using gsm a6

Tags: server, arduino, gsm

I'm using a6 gsm module with Arduino Mega and I want to send specific data values to the server (https://000webhost.com) and after that to mySQL data base which is in (https://www.clever-cloud.com). First, I tried with apache server on my pc and it was successful attempt. But when I use 000webhost.com I get an error in serial monitor - CME ERROR:58. PHP files are same. This is the code which I'm using:

```
void send() { 
delay(500);
Serial3.println("AT+CIPSHUT\r");
delay(1000);
Serial3.println("AT+CIPMUX=0\r");
delay(500);
Serial3.println("AT+CGATT=1\r");
delay(500);
Serial3.println("AT+CSTT=\"internet\",\"\",\"\"\r");
delay(500); 
Serial3.println("AT+CIICR\r"); 
delay(1000);
Serial3.println("AT+CIFSR\r");
delay(1000);
Serial3.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"test.000webhostapp.com\", 80\r"); 
delay(1000); 
Serial3.println("AT+CIPSEND\r");
delay(1000);
printSerialData(); 
Serial3.println("POST http://test.000webhostapp.com/send.php HTTP/1.1");
delay(250);
Serial3.println("Host: test.000webhostapp.com");
delay(250);
Serial3.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
delay(250);
Serial3.println("Content-Length: 9\r\n");
delay(250);
Serial3.println("i=15&p=69");
delay(250); 
Serial3.write(0x1A);
// Ctrl Z delay(5000);
Serial3.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
delay(750);
Serial3.println("AT+CIPSHUT");
delay(750);
printSerialData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try your code with curl before?
Can you look at logs in the same time?